# In Modal Presentation Navigationbar is not getting displayed

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I want to have Navigation bar/navigationcontroller while Modal component presentation.

I have tried this way using

```
render() {
return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.isModalVisible}
        >
<Component
            toggle={this.toggle}
          />
        </Modal>
</SafeAreaView>
)
```

In AppContainer

```
const ModalNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MainApp: {
    screen: RootStack
  },
  ComponentModal: {
    screen: Component,
    navigationOptions: {
      //title:'Add Prospect'
    }
  }
}, {
  headerMode:'none',
  mode:'modal',
})
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(ModalNavigator);
```

But this didn't workout. Can someone help me to fix this

Comment: refer this https://medium.com/4thought-studios/better-modals-in-react-navigation-56c649e0249

Comment: Hi @hongdevelop, Thank u for sharing, but there he is using 
import Header from 'react-navigation/src/views/Header/Header';
which source path is not available in current react-navigation